# Problemas com formulários

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu estou tentando fazer um formulário utilizando js e php, só que quando eu clico no botão de enviar, permanece sempre com "Enviando e-mail..." e nunca envia, eu chequei console e diz que o erro está no email.php (404 error not found)... Se alguém puder me ajudar, segue abaixo os códigos que eu utilizei:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contact-form">
     <h3>Contate-nos</h3>
          <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post"  action="email.php">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nome">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
               </div>
               <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Mensagem</button>
         </form>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
       var form = $('#main-contact-form');
       form.submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
           var data = {
               name: $('#name').val(),
               email: $('#email').val(),
               subject: $('#subject').val(),
               message: $('#message').val()
           };
           $.ajax({
               url: $(this).attr('action'),
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               data: {'data': data},
               beforeSend: function(){
                   form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando email...</p>').fadeIn() );
               },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == 1){
                    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Sucesso!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
                else{
                    form_status.html('<p class="text-error">Desculpe,
tente novamente!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
         });
    });
   </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$name       = $data['name'];
$from       = $data['email'];
$subject    = $data['subject'];
$message    = $data['message'];
$to         = 'user@email.com';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 1;
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: O arquivo `email.php` existe ? Encontra-se no mesmo diretório que esse arquivo *HTML* ?

Comment: fica, este php que coloquei ai é o email.php

Comment: O nome do arquivo está correto ? Porque erro `404` quer quiser que não existe ou não encontrado, praticamente a mesma coisa. Está usando `.htaccess` ? Se sim, coloque na pergunta.

Comment: pois é, eu já chequei várias vezes e até renomeei, mas está correto sim :c, não estou utilizando htacess

Comment: Qual o caminha completo que aparece no `Console` na aba *Network* ?

Comment: Dentro do seu `ajax` tem este código `url: $(this).attr('action'),` imprime ele no console e veja se esta carregando o link correto de `email.php`, `console.log($(this).attr('action'));`

Comment: so deu  undefined

Comment: Seu erro não está no Ajax nem nada, está exclusivamente no PHP. Seu código de envio de email não funciona, está retornando erro, por isso seu formulário não avança. Reveja esse código de envio porque está errado.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que deveria escrever novamente seu código *JavaScript*, veja esse exemplo:

```js
$( "#formulario" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: { nome: $("[name='nome']").val(), msg: $("[name='msg']").val() }
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data.form);
  });
  
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  width: 250px;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  background: #069;
  border: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<form id="formulario" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
  <p><input type="text" name="nome" value="Stackoverflow Português :)"></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="msg" value="O script está funcionando :D"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>
```